# Wrong Icon Installed by Xcode

Tags: ios, icons, xcode5, universal, asset-catalog

I have been pulling my hairs for the past few days. It appears I am the first one who has experienced this problem because I could not find anything that is even close through Internet searches. The problem that I have experienced is the following:

Icon for retina iPad of iOS 6.1 and prior (size 144x144) and Icon for iPhone of iOS 7 (size 120x120) are not installed correctly. If I use asset catalog, when installing my app on iPad (retina) with iOS 5, the iPhone icon (120x120) is installed. iPhone with iOS 7 works fine using the same icon (120x120). If I don't use asset catalog, but instead add the icons to the info.plist (CFBundleIcons array), it goes the other way around. iPad icon is fine this time (144x144 icon was installed). But iPhone uses the iPad icon (144x144).

What's more strange is that this is not a problem with one of my two targets. It is only a problem for the second target. The second target was created by duplicating the first one. I have compared the info and settings of the two projects, but did not see any difference (other than bundle identifiers and product names etc., of course).

I've upgraded my Xcode to 5.0.2 and that makes no difference.

I'd appreciate it if anybody could shed some light on this.

Update #1: I tried to use the icons from the first target and the problem is still there. So it's not related the icon png files. It's target related. Also tried to clean the project, delete the app from the devices to no avail.

Update #2: When I use plist instead of asset catalog, what's (incorrectly) installed on my iPhone (iOS 7) is not the 144x144 icon. It is 144x144 icon for iOS 6.1 and prior. It's still an incorrect icon.

Update #3: This is actually easy to reproduce. I created a cocos2d project from scratch this time (the Hello World project). Tried to add all the icons using the two ways introduced in the following technical article from Apple:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1686/_index.html

When using the asset catalog, 120x120 icon was installed on my iPad (retina) with iOS 5.
When using the project editor, 152x152 icon was installed on my iPad (retina) with iOS 5.

In both cases, what is supposed to be installed is the 144x144 icon. Will probably contact Apple on Monday.

Answer (score 1):

I filed a tech-support case with Apple and confirmed that this is a known issue (as of 02/10/14). I open a bug report with Apple. This issue is not noticeable for most people because icons are all resized from one design. Even though the wrong icon is installed, it is barely noticeable (the icon is still resized to to the correct size on the device automatically). This is noticeable when you want to use different icon design on different iOS. For example, the icon curvature for iOS 7 is different. There is no workaround according to the Apple support.

Hope this is useful for anyone who runs into the same issue.

Regards,
Ryan

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you don't have the older icons named with the an older version of Xcode's default icon names (Icon.png, Icon@2x.png, Icon-72.png). I have found that when these names exist, they are used even if other icon names are specified.

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning the project. Command-Shift-K , that usually fixes such issues

Comment: Additionally deleting the installed app from device or simulator has worked for me.

Comment: Unfortunately, deep clean did not help either. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Ok, then there's only one other explanation, try going into your apps folder on disk, if my hunch is right, your original icon is probably still there. If it is, delete it.

Comment: You mean the app on the simulator? I tried it on a device. I just tried to replace all the icons with those from the first target. The wrong one was installed. But this time, it was the wrong one from the first target. So it's not some cached icon.

Comment: Had this problem with a physical device. Cleaning, removing the app from device, rebooting device and installing again fixed it for me.

Comment: Nice find @RikuVirta. I had an icon which wouldn't update until I rebooted my simulator! I guess the OS is caching the icons, even over re-installs!